# Convert Postgres Date to JS Date without Timestamp

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm returning a date from postgres in the format `2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` for example.

I want to convert it to a JS Date then to a string, and strip the time off it so I just get `'01/01/2008'` ( so mm/dd/yyyy)

Not sure how to do this, I've searched but don't see a way yet.

Comment: Is the front end getting the string  "2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"?

Comment: no I want the front-end to get the simple date

Comment: I'm actually returning it via GraphQL as well back to the client

Comment: I'm confused. So you're not able to just do `new Date("2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` and format the string from that?

Comment: So am I. ES6 string commands are also very good and could easily solve your problem

Comment: I'm saying I'm not sure how to format a string using Date.  I couldn't find a good way to do so with Date() taking the format I showed above and stripping out the timestamp

Comment: You might like to take a look at:
https://codeofmatt.com/javascript-date-parsing-changes-in-es6/

Answer (score 1):

[moment](https://momentjs.com/) is a fine library for working with dates in JavaScript.

But if you wanted to do this with vanilla JavaScript, you could do the following:

```js
let date = new Date("2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
let formattedDate = `${(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
dateSpan.innerHTML = formattedDate;
```

```html
<span id="dateSpan"></span>
```

Note that JavaScript will display the date in local time. If you want to keep it in UTC, you could use `getUTC` as follows:

```js
let date = new Date("2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
let formattedDate = `${(date.getUTCMonth() + 1)}/${date.getUTCDate()}/${date.getUTCFullYear()}`;
dateSpan.innerHTML = formattedDate;
```

```html
<span id="dateSpan"></span>
```

Again, nothing wrong with moment, but just figured I'd provide a vanilla JS example as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just resorted to using [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

`moment(dateFromPostgres).format('L')`